# How use OAuth token to make a authenticated request in GitHub API

Tags: node.js

guys. Today i have a new question.

I need make a request to GitHub API, this request get package.json for the selected repo.

```
var apiRequest = api('/repos/' + self.settings.org + '/' + self.repo + '/contents/package.json', {
        token: self.settings.gitToken,
    });
```

The problem is, GitHub approve only 60 requests to non authenticated app. And some repos, make more of 60 request. I learn in internet forums foro that is necessary that my app make a authenticated request to GitHub API, i have GitHub OAuth token, and API url and callback url, registered in github.

Comment: What is the problem or error? You have registered the app and got the token. Where are you stuck now?

Comment: Github continuing blocking my app for exceded requests